# How to terminate a thread even if it has not finished running?

Tags: java, multithreading, terminate

My program start a thread whether some objects is created.

```
Foo() {
   t = new Thread(this);
   t.start();
}
```

And I am running some while loop inside my threads.

```
while(bool){
   // do something
}
```

I have one thread controlling the value of the boolean bool. But how can I terminate some of them before my other thread change the boolean value? I think setting t = null doesn't work. Is there any way to garbage collect the thread before it stop running?

Comment: [Implement your own interruption mechanism.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: The Thread instance has nothing to do with the underlying thread of execution. GCing it won't magically cause a thread to stop executing, much like GCing a File instance won't delete the file.

Comment: It's important to note that `bool` needs to be a `volatile boolean` so it can be changed and read by multiple threads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317702/how-should-i-terminate-a-looped-sub-thread-in-java

Comment: Don't start a thread from the constructor. The new thread may observe the new object in an uninitialized state. This might occur even if the `start` call is at the end of the constructor, because of memory ordering issues. Write a static factory method instead, construct the object there, and **then** start the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the loop to

```
while (bool && !Thread.interrupted()) {
    // do something
}
```

When you want to stop the thread, call

```
t.interrupt();
```

Good luck.

Comment: Or even better, remove the bool, since it's used to do the same thing as what the interrupt flag already does.

Comment: He might be using bool to control it within the loop in stead of break. :)

Comment: It's always a good idea to use `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` instead so the interrupt status is not cleared.